# Why do we use the form $f(t)=ae^{kt}$ for exponential growth and decay?

Tags: exponentiation, exponential-function

Why do we include the $e^{k}$?

Wouldn't it be easier to simply use $f(t)=ap^{t}$ where $p$ is the percentage increase per time.

Is there a reason why the convention is to use $f(t)=ae^{kt}$?

Comment: Shouldn't those be $f(t)$ rather than $x$?

Comment: Oops, you're right. I'll change it right now.

Comment: It is not widely known, but growth and decay problems led to the name of an important modern area of study, Grothendieck K-theory. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_group and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-theory

Comment: P.S. say them out loud...

Answer (score 1):

See also: [What's so "natural" about the base of natural logarithms?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/797/whats-so-natural-about-the-base-of-natural-logarithms)

The choice of base is arbitrary, but the primary reason is likely that the defining equation for the system looks like
$$\frac{df}{dt}=kf.$$
This means that the rate of growth of the population is proportional (proportionality $k$) to the population at a given time. The solution is $f(t)=ae^{kt}$. It can be re-expressed as you said, but there is no benefit.