# Why do we write complex numbers as $e^{i \theta} $?

Tags: complex-numbers

Why can't we write complex numbers as $2^{i \theta} $ or $-40^{i \theta} $? Why does it have to be $e$?

Comment: Not all complex numbers have that form, only those on the unit circle...

Comment: We can. But we are used to parametrize the unit circle with $\theta \in [0, 2\pi]$, not $\theta \in [0, 2\pi/\log 2]$.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_%28mathematical_constant%29#e_in_calculus  and  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/797/whats-so-natural-about-the-base-of-natural-logarithms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know that complex numbers can be expressed as $$\cos { \theta  } +i\sin { \theta  } ,$$ and we want to express this form as  $$a^{i\theta}=\cos { \theta  } +i\sin { \theta  } .$$ Take the second derivatives fo the both equation: $$\frac { { d }^{ 2 } }{ d{ \theta  }^{ 2 } } \left( { a }^{ i\theta  } \right) =\frac { { d }^{ 2 } }{ d{ \theta  }^{ 2 } } (\cos { \theta  } +i\sin { \theta  } )\\ -{ a }^{ i\theta  }{ \left( \ln { a }  \right)  }^{ 2 }=-(\cos { \theta  } +i\sin { \theta  } )=-{ a }^{ i\theta  }\\ a=e$$

Answer (score 4):

$e$ is a special number. See [**here**](http://www.math.wisc.edu/~dummit/docs/calc2_3_complex_numbers.pdf).

Comment: we don't write it like that because $e$ is special, $e$ is special because of that :D

Answer (score 3):

Because of Euler's formula $e^{ix} = \cos{x}+i\sin{x}$.

Comment: I dont think that actually answers the question...

Answer (score 3):

We can, actually : $2^i$ means $\cos\ln2+i\sin\ln2$, for instance... :-) The only difference is that, in the case of *e*, its natural logarithm ‘disappears’, thus becoming ‘invisible’ in the expression’s final form.