# Derivative of log(y)

Tags: derivatives

I am quite stuck on how to differentiate log(y) with respect to y. When I googled it, I seen many websites state that d(log(y))/dy is 1/yln(10). However, the question I have attached requires me to differentiate xylog(y) w/ respect to y, but I got a different answer to my teacher. I have attached the question, teacher’s answer & my answer. Thanks [image: My answer][image: question][image: Teacher’s answer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are interpreting the question as using base $10$ while your teacher uses base $e$ for the logarithm.

Hence the difference in your solution.

Your answer is correct if base $10$ is indeed used in the logarithm though the popular default is base $e$ in calculus. Not always, but popular.

Edit:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(xy \log_b y)=x \log_b y+\frac{xy}{\ln b}$$

You are treating the question as $b=10$ while your teacher is treating $b=e$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When I changed the base to e, I got an answer of (x+xln(y))/ln(10), which is still different to my teacher’s answer and im not sure why.

Comment: Your teacher is computing $\frac{\partial}{\partial y} (xy \ln y)$.

Comment: So did he make a mistake?

Comment: when a typical maths person write $\log$, he means $\log_e$. You two are answering different questions.

Comment: I thought log is assumed to be log base 10 and ln is log base e

Comment: yup, that is how most are taught at secondary school. but as you go higher, most people use base $e$.

Comment: Ah this is so annoying. People should stick to the right convention. Thank you for clearing this up for me though, much appreciated

Comment: For your interest, a discussion link on the [choice](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/797/306553).